# Determine how many times IME_ACTION_GO is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, ime, raw-input

I am trying to run a method when the enter button is pressed 1 time.

If it is pressed 2 or more times, I don't want to run the method, and I want to `RawInputType` and/or `IMEOptions` to return to normal enter button functionality.

How can I achieve this function?

**My code so far**

```
public int press = 0;

bodyText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
bodyText.setImeOptions(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);

    bodyText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                if (press == 0) {
                    press += 1;
                    // Run "the" method
                }
                if (press >= 1) {
                    // Don't run "the" method ever
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where are you calling the method? You should only call the method in if( press == 0 ) {}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is almost there, but it seems you are returning true no matter what, which is consuming the event, meaning the default functionality will not run after press > 0.

You will want to only return true when the press == 0, something along the lines of:

```
if (press == 0) {
    // Run method here
    return true;
} else {
    // Return false to indicate that the event was not consumed so the default
    // behavior is executed.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That helps! But now the keyboard closes and normal enter button function doesn't return after the second press. Any ideas?

Comment: That's strange, it might be useful to add some logging and make sure that it is returning false on the second press.